# Make dynamically generate table stay in form when not enough item in row

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, foreach

I am working with asp.net MVC. I have dynamically generate table with 5 items in a row on my view. But I have a problem when model have not enough 5 items, items width will increase to fill in row like below:

```
| x | x | x | x | x | (when have >=5 item)

|    x    |    x    | (when have <5 item, in this case is 2)

| x | x |             (what I want to display)
```

This is my cshtml code:

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%">
    @{
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var thread in Model)
        {
            if (count % 5 == 0)
            {
                @:<tr>
            }
            <td style="width:20%">
                //thread details here
            </td>
            count++;
            if (count % 5 == 0)
            {
                @:</tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>
```

I can change to 2 items per row or use fix width in , but it is not my goal. 
Can you suggest me some way to improve my table?

Comment: Remove `style="width:20%"` from `td`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i tried it, and nothing changed. I want 2 items display in 40% table's size (total size for 5 items).

Comment: Use a fixed width for the `<td>` elements and remove `width:100%` from the `<table>` element

Comment: Can you check your browser developer tools(Press F12) for `colspan` in `td`.

Comment: Yes, fixed width will solve my problem, but I used width with % to fit more sreen size. Any suggest?

Comment: @Pugazh : It don't have `colspan` , because my code just generate 2 <td> if there are 2 items instead of 5.

Comment: If you want to have 100% screen width then you could ensure in the controller that your collection count is a multiple of 5, and if not add extra 'default' `thread` elements so that when you generate `//thread details here` it outputs an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by add more blank `<td>` in row if my items smaller than 5. Now it display like I want

```
<table style="width:100%;height:100%">
@{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var thread in Model)
    {
        if (count % 5 == 0)
        {
            @:<tr>
        }
        <td style="width:20%">
            //thread details here
        </td>
        count++;
        if (count % 5 == 0)
        {
            @:</tr>
        }
    }
    while (count%5!=0)
    {
        <td></td>
        count++;
    }
    @:</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: I have replicated your code and it displays the second row as you want (the 2 columns take up 40% of the width, not 100%) so I suspect you may have some other css interfering. Have you tried adding a `<thead>` with a `<tr>` containing 5 `<th>` elements and setting the width on the `<th>` elements? Note also you should be using css, not inline styles like that.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, `<thead>` and css file are good ideals.